# sequence contains no matching element but it contains element when I insert a break point

Tags: c#-3.0

I have this code:

```
int gts_size=20;
int gts_type=1;

var r = from room in collection_of_rooms.rooms
        where gts_size <= room.capacity_of_room 
        select room;

var r2 = r.First<Room>(rr => (rr.room_type == gts_type)); // here is the error
```

rooms is array of class "Room" , which has fields: capacity_of_room and room_type

exception thrown with message "sequence contains no matching element"
**but** when I insert a break point to trace the code, it works properly and  r1,r2 have values.
I have tried FirstOrDefault() and the same is still happening.

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Are you sure the inputs are the same when you are debugging. I see absolutely no problem with your code. Have you checked the counts of both collections. Also, note that FirstOfDefault should be used instead, as it does not require any additional exception handling. You can just test the result for null later.